# Code Execution cannot proceed because SDL2.dll was not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, sdl-2

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 with c++ code. I'm working on a new project and Visual Studio has no issues building the code, however when I actually run the program I get this error.

[image: Image of Error]

I have SDL2 installed as I have another program that runs just fine. So I'm not really sure what the issue is here.

Comment: is sdl2.dll in the same directory as the executable?

Comment: Yes it was solved by having the dll in the same folder as the exacutable (i guess the Visual Studio 2019 executable) I don't know if this solves your problem Minxin Yu, but it seems to work for the author.

Answer (score -2):

you can copy the SDL2.dll to the systemm32 folder and that should solve your problem

Comment: Bad idea. It should be placed in the same directory as the .exe.